# Why don't check the range overflow when converting "Number" to "Float" or "Double" in Spring Boot framework source code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, frameworks

please look at the source code snippet that is from `org.springframework.util.NumberUtils#convertNumberToTargetClass()`, the method signature is `+ <T extends Number> T convertNumberToTargetClass(number:Number, targetClass:Class<?>)`

```
public static <T extends Number> T convertNumberToTargetClass(Number number, Class<T> targetClass)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
    ... ...
    ... ...
    else if (Float.class == targetClass) {
        return (T) Float.valueOf(number.floatValue());
    }
    .... ....
    .... ....
}
```

When converting `number` to `Float`, it doesn't check whether the `number` overflows the range of `Float` or not. But it does check that when converting number to `Byte`, `Integer` or `Short`, as showing below:

```
    public static <T extends Number> T convertNumberToTargetClass(Number number, Class<T> targetClass)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        ... ...
        ... ...
        else if (Byte.class == targetClass) {
            long value = checkedLongValue(number, targetClass);
            if (value < Byte.MIN_VALUE || value > Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
                raiseOverflowException(number, targetClass);
            }
            return (T) Byte.valueOf(number.byteValue());
        }
        ... ...
        ... ...
    }

    private static long checkedLongValue(Number number, Class<? extends Number> targetClass) {
        BigInteger bigInt = null;
        if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
            bigInt = (BigInteger) number;
        }
        else if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
            bigInt = ((BigDecimal) number).toBigInteger();
        }
        // Effectively analogous to JDK 8's BigInteger.longValueExact()
        if (bigInt != null && (bigInt.compareTo(LONG_MIN) < 0 || bigInt.compareTo(LONG_MAX) > 0)) {
            raiseOverflowException(number, targetClass);
        }
        return number.longValue();
    }

    private static void raiseOverflowException(Number number, Class<?> targetClass) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not convert number [" + number + "] of type [" +
            number.getClass().getName() + "] to target class [" + targetClass.getName() + "]: overflow");
    }
```

I'm really curious why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no overflow.

If you do something like this:

```
Float aFloat = NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(Double.MAX_VALUE, Float.class);
```

The value of aFloat will be Infinity.

Checkout the API doc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html

Comment: Of cause, `aFloat` should be infinity in the above case, but using such infinite value has no meaning. As soon as encounter such infinite `aFloat`, shouldn't we throw an `Exception` or let the execution stream continue ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I see. The goal to check whether it overflows or underflows or not when convert a Number to a non-fraction number is to prevent from an incorrect calculation result. If we don't check that, we will be overhead. But refer to floating-point numbers, overflow and NAN won't result in wrong calculation result. We can definitely recognize the wrong operation by checking the 'infinite' result. The best way to make frame code most generic is leaving checking infinite calculation result to clients.